# Returning handle to calling script perl

Tags: perl

I have an executable which can run perl scripts using the following command at the prompt:
blah.exe Launch.pl

The way we have our tests setup is that we call the Launch.pl from Parent.pl like this "blah.exe Launch.pl" - script within script. However, when executing the command with backticks/system command the parent .pl script execution waits till I get the handle back by closing and exiting out of the application (blah.exe). At this point the code in parent.pl continues to execute.

How do I return the handle back to the parent .pl script after I get done running the code that is contained in the Launch.pl

So, parent.pl calls "blah.exe Launch.pl"; but after running the code inside Launch.pl inside the application (blah.exe) it just sits there waiting to be exited out of so that the code in parent.pl can continue running. I need to keep the application (blah.exe) open till I am done running a bunch of scripts one after another.

Answer (score 1):

Run `blah.exe` [in the background](http://learn.perl.org/faq/perlfaq8.html#How-do-I-start-a-process-in-the-background-). When you are done with the `Parent.pl`, terminate the application with [`kill`](http://p3rl.org/kill).